# Syntax Error: Unexpected end of file

Tags: bash, debugging

I'm trying to run this script below and I have no idea why its not working.  I keep getting an error message that says "Syntax Error: Unexpected end of file" and I don't know how to trouble shoot this

```
#!/bin/bash

Add_Entry(){

        echo "Go Flight"
        pause
}

Delete_Entry(){

        echo "Go Flight"
        pause
}

View_Entry() {

        echo "Go Flight"
        pause

Show_menus() {

        echo "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
        echo " M A I N - M E N U"
        echo "~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~"
        echo "1. Add Entry"
        echo "2. Delete Entry"
        echo "3. View Entry"
        echo "4. Exit"
}

Exit(){

        exit
}

Read_options(){

        echo "Please choose from the menu"
        read choice
        case $choice in
                1) Add_Entry ;;
                2) Delete_Entry ;;
                3) View_Entry ;;
                4) Exit ;;
        esac
}

# Main
while true
do

        Show_menus
        Read_options
done
```

The Add Entry, View Entry and Delete Entry are just full of dummy code at the moment.  Still I have no idea why I'm getting this error.  Any help would be most appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `View_Entry()` block isn't closed. i.e. it should be

```
View_Entry() {

        echo "Go Flight"
        pause

}
```

Fixing this makes the script work for me. If you use a text editor with syntax hightlighting (e.g. `vim` or `kate`, perhaps `gedit`?) this is easy to spot.